# Terraform Import Massive records

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

I'm terraforming an infrastructure that was never in Terraform before. I have like 300 Route53 records. I used `terraform import` command to import into state until I realised it's not wise to do for each records because there are a lot of them.

I tried a tool called `terraforming` but looks like the state isn't getting updated well. After import, when I do `terraform plan`, I see a lot of stuff that will be created. This is wrong.

I have blocks like:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "examplerecord" {
   zone_id = "zone_id"
   name    = "name"
   type    = "NS"
   records = [""]
```

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "examplezone" {
   name       = "name"
   comment    = "comment"
   tags {
   }
}
```

How can I achieve achieve importing all the records at once into Terraform state? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `terraforming`, but to do what you want with raw `terraform` would already be a pain, as you need to create the blank resource entries in your .tf file.

Assuming this is a one-off thing, I would just write a short program that uses the AWS API to get all the relevant records, and then reformat them as terraform configurations. Something like

```py
r = boto3.client('route53')
for hz in r.list_hosted_zones()['HostedZones']
  # ... output an "aws_route53_zone" record
  for rrs in r.list_resource_record_sets(HostedZoneId=hz['HostedZoneId']):
    for rr in rrs['ResourceRecordSets']:
      # ... output an aws_route53_record"
```

You get the idea. You can tell I've done this before :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer).

It can import all of your r53 records to your state and generate terraform code at the same time.